# Finding out when a td element shows ellipsis

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table in which the cells show ellipsis if too long. I set overflow: hidden and text-overflow: ellipsis on the td elements.

I now need to show a tooltip if the user hovers a cell that can't fit the entire text, but no tooltip on other cells.

I can register an event to capture mouseover, but how can I tell if the hovered td shows ellipsis or not?

Comment: I think you'd have to check the width of the contents against the width of the cell. Can you put together a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), for us to experiment with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the scrollWidth of the content and compare it to the width of the element.
Here's a solution with jQuery:

```
$('td').each(function () {
    if ($(this)[0].scrollWidth > $(this).innerWidth()) {
        // Text is overflowing
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AvJvW/